# How well do Canon EF lens adapters for Sony E-mount perform?

Tags: lens-adapter, sony-nex, canon-ef

I have been looking into a potential adapter to use Canon EF lenses on the Sony α6000 and a Google search isn't giving a clear example of a quality adapter. I'm looking to use my husband's EF 24-70mm f/2.8 II and EF 70-200mm f/2.8 USM IS II on the Sony α6000.

The question is, has anybody used these adapters and do they hold up in quality?

Comment: It should be noted that current answers here and on the related question are rapidly falling out of date. The newer Sony Alpha series cameras, including the forthcoming A6100 (due in a month or two here), have significantly improved AF compatibility with third party lenses thanks to phase detection AF. The Metabones IV adapter (and I believe a new one, probably the V?) support fast AF with Canon EF lenses, and there is a new adapter that supports fast AF with Nikon F lenses as well. Upgrading the a6000 to the a6100 when it hits the streets with a metabones will give you fast AF.

Comment: @jrista, you should post that as an answer on the other question, and mention the outdating of the other answers at the top. I've done that a number of times with older flash trigger questions, and even got an accepted answer switched.

Answer (score 3):

Other answers have already said what I'd have said, apart from the fact that the only reason I'd use one of these adapters is if I had Canon lenses *and* you want IS.  Having IS is arguably the most useful advantage these adapters offer, as shooting with adapted lenses with dumb adapters is quite simple.

> I'm looking to use my husbands EF 24-70 f2.8 II and EF 70-200 f2.8 USM IS II on the Sony a6000.

I'm sure you must know this, but for general information, note that the size *and weight* of these lenses is significant and, if you do this, mount the lenses on a tripod or monopod and do **not** rely on the Sony's mount being strong enough to support these lenses.

Using these lenses on a DSLR is less of a problem for handling and balance, but on a small camera like the A6000 it just feels weird in my experience.  YMMV.

Comment: I presume you own older Nikon, Leica R, or C/Y lenses because modern Canon and Nikon lenses do not have aperture rings and are of extremely limited usefulness on standard adapters.

Comment: I have mostly older Pentax lenses these days.  I have used cheap adapters for Nikon lenses without aperture rings on my own NEX.  It's doable, but you loose precision in the aperture you're shooting at.  This is OK for exposure purposes as the NEX does the metering anyway, and with a bit of practice you get ballpark the desired aperture for DOF.  I mostly use a focal reducer adapter these days.

Comment: Well, Nikon G lenses still have a physical lever in the mount by which an adapter with its own ring can actuate the aperture physically. You're right it works pretty well; the Metabones Nikon G adapter even has click stops [though I don't know how accurate]. Canon EF lenses do not have that lever, though, and even Nikon's new E lenses have dropped it.

Answer (score 1):

Brian Smith has a [roundup of various adapters for Sony E-mount cameras](http://briansmith.com/gear/sony-lens-adapters/) to mount many different types of lenses. In the "Canon EF to Sony E-Mount Lens Adapters" section, he lists the following adapters:

1. Metabones Canon EF to Sony E-Mount Smart Adapter IV ($400)
2. FotodioX AF Adapter for Canon EF to Sony E-Mount ($100)
3. Viltrox Auto-focus Canon EF/EF-S Lens to Sony E Mount Adapter II ($100)

He liked all of them, preferring the Metabones for quality, and the FotodioX for budget. He notes that none of them are fast focusing, so while they would work fine for portraits and landscapes, you will find them slow for sports shooting.

---

[This thread at dpreview.com](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3655232#forum-post-53489773) discusses using Canon EF lenses on the a6000. Autofocus speed of the various adapters mentioned there was the most common issue mentioned. The last couple of posts to that thread each indicated they used cheap adapters ("Commlite" and "Lengril" brands), and were more or less satisfied with them as well.

Comment: I've heard it said that with the latest IV version and the latest firmware Metabones' Canon AF isn't so terribly slow anymore. Don't know if it's true.